# whereIn with 2D-Array?

Tags: php, laravel

When I use a 2d-array with `whereIn`, I got an array-to-string conversion exception.

It is possible to use whereIn with a 2d-array like codeigniter?

**Edit:**

And i have a second question.
When I use whereIn with an array I don't get any result.
But when I use the query in phpmyadmin I get a result.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [query] => select * from `tab_articles` inner join `tab_categories` on `tab_categories`.`category_id` = `tab_articles`.`category_id` where `article_id` in (?) [bindings] => Array ( [article_id] => 4 ) [time] => 0.79 ) )
```

The array is not empty. The ID exists in the database and is use `get()` to get the result, but there is nothing in array. It's strange.

Comment: Please consider moving your second question to a second question. When you edit in additional questions, you invalidate existing answers and make it more difficult for answerers who now have to response to both.

Comment: Sorry, next time i will do this, because i found the solution for my second question and its my first day and question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

But, if your array is an Eloquent Collection, you could use the modelKeys function.

```
$query->whereIn($collection->modelKeys());
```

This function returns an array of the primary keys of your models.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L92

Comment: Okay i found the mistake...
I did something like this: $array = array('id' => $id), but this is not working. 
The solution is an array and only the ids, without any keys.